# Jquery - loop of ajax in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So i have this array of stuff that it needs to be updated, but since async:false was deprecated and it needs to be one by one to show the progress of the update, is any way to do this with ajax.success?, example:

```
progressUpdate(stuff[0].name, 100 / stuff.length)
for(var f = 0; f < stuff.length; f++){

  $.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    global: true,
    url: '/stuffs/'+stuff[f].id+'.json',
    contentType: 'application/json', 
    dataType: 'script', 
    data: JSON.stringify({stuff:{set: 1}, _method:'put'})
  });


  //Wait here to finish updating, then continue increase the progressbar

  progressUpdate(stuff[f].name, 100 / stuff.length)     
}
```

I try to put the progressUpdate() inside the success but is not in the order of the array, since it updates when it recives the callback, some of the posterior elements finish before the previous element, like this

```
....
.success: funcion(){
  progressUpdate(stuff[f].name, 100 / stuff.length)
}
....
```

Is there any way to do this progression in order?

Comment: may be you can try doing it with promises.. when your promise is resolved then make call again to progressUpdate. This way you will have complete control of your execution order.
 $.ajax itself returns a promise so promise should be a way to go for this.
If you can show some more of your code then we may try refactoring the code for the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this ?

```
do_job(stuff, 0); // Launch first job

function do_job(stuff, index) {
  if (index < stuff.length)
  {
    $.ajax({
      type: "PUT",
      global: true,
      url: '/stuffs/'+stuff[f].id+'.json',
      contentType: 'application/json', 
      dataType: 'script', 
      data: JSON.stringify({stuff:{set: 1}, _method:'put'}),
      success: function(data) {
        // Job finished, let's begin the next one
        progressUpdate(stuff[index].name, 100 / stuff.length)   
        do_job(stuff, index + 1); // actual index (your variable "f") + 1
      }
    });
  } else {
    // every stuff is finished
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to make it update the stuff in order would be to call for the next update only on the success of the previous. Something like this

```
function updateStuff(f){
   if(f < stuff.length){
      ajax stuff ...
      success: funcion(){
         progressUpdate(stuff[f].name, 100 / stuff.length)
         updateStuff(f+1);
      }
   }
}
```

And call updateStuff(0) to start the recursion.